# What did the almonds on the Menorah (Lamp of the Presence) represent in Exodus 37:20

Tags: exodus, symbolism, tabernacle

> Exodus 25:9
>
> "According to all that I show you, that is, the pattern of the
> tabernacle and the pattern of all its furnishings, just so you shall
> make it.
>
> Exodus 25:40
>
> "And see to it that you make them according to the **pattern** which
> was shown you on the mountain.
>
> Exodus 37:20
>
> And on the lampstand itself were four bowls made like **almond
> blossoms**, each with its ornamental knob and flower.

What is the significance, meaning or symbolism attached to the presence of the almonds on the lamp of the Presence?

Comment: it seems they signify that God is watching & they will be a time of reckoning for every deed( Jeremiah 1:11-12)

Comment: @collenndhlovu that's an  interesting interpretation. The almond = Shakeid in hebrew which means "wakeful" or "hastening". In Jeremiah it was used as "hastening" because God was going to hasten his word to perform it.

Answer (score 1):

To get a picture of almonds lets go to numbers 17:
Numbers 17:8

> 8 And it came to pass, that on the morrow Moses went into the
>   tabernacle of witness; and, behold, the rod of Aaron for the house of
>   Levi was budded, and brought forth buds, and bloomed blossoms, and
>   yielded almonds.
>   In this case the almonds a testimony of the life projected by the quickening power when the dead sinner brought into the  presence of the Shekinah glory, in type The Holy Ghost. Note hear an almond is a nut and a nut is a seed. The reproductive life is in the seed, the almond seed.
>   To get a beautiful picture of this life after death let us go to

Ephesians 2:1-6

> 1 And you hath he quickened, who were dead in trespasses and sins:
>
> 2 Wherein in time past ye walked according to the course of this
>   world, according to the prince of the power of the air, the spirit
>   that now worketh in the children of disobedience:
>
> 3 Among whom also we all had our conversation in times past in the
>   lusts of our flesh, fulfilling the desires of the flesh and of the
>   mind; and were by nature the children of wrath, even as others.
>
> 4 But God, who is rich in mercy, for his great love wherewith he loved
>   us,
>
> 5 Even when we were dead in sins, hath quickened us together with
>   Christ, (by grace ye are saved;)
>
> 6 And hath raised us up together, and made us sit together in heavenly
>   places in Christ Jesus:

You see the way to the Holy of holies was opened at the cross of Calvary, to make way for the sinner to enter in and bud, bloom blossom, and yield almonds. The almonds testifies of the work and fruit of Grace, through the  sanctification that is by Faith in His name.
Paul puts it this way:

Hebrews 10:19-22

> 19 Having therefore, brethren, boldness to enter into the holiest by
>   the blood of Jesus,
>
> 20 By a new and living way, which he hath consecrated for us, through
>   the veil, that is to say, his flesh;
>
> 21 And having an high priest over the house of God;
>
> 22 Let us draw near with a true heart in full assurance of faith,
>   having our hearts sprinkled from an evil conscience, and our bodies
>   washed with pure water.

An almond is a present of honour given to an honourable person. When Jacob sent presents to the man of honour in Egypt he sent almond. In this case an almond is an acceptable offering, acceptable service.

Genesis 43:11

> 11 And their father Israel said unto them, If it must be so now, do
>   this; take of the best fruits in the land in your vessels, and carry
>   down the man a present, a little balm, and a little honey, spices, and
>   myrrh, nuts, and almonds:

We read again in the scriptures:

Romans 12:1

> 1 I beseech you therefore, brethren, by the mercies of God, that ye
>   present your bodies a living sacrifice, holy, acceptable unto God,
>   which is your reasonable service.

Paul puts it this way:

Romans 15:15,16

> 15 Nevertheless, brethren, I have written the more boldly unto you in
>   some sort, as putting you in mind, because of the grace that is given
>   to me of God,
>
> 16 That I should be the minister of Jesus Christ to the Gentiles,
>   ministering the gospel of God, that the offering up of the Gentiles
>   might be acceptable, being sanctified by the Holy Ghost.

In exodus we read:

Exodus 25:31-34

> 31 And thou shalt make a candlestick of pure gold: of beaten work
>   shall the candlestick be made: his shaft, and his branches, his bowls,
>   his knops, and his flowers, shall be of the same.
>
> 32 And six branches shall come out of the sides of it; three branches
>   of the candlestick out of the one side, and three branches of the
>   candlestick out of the other side:
>
> 33 Three bowls made like unto almonds, with a knop and a flower in one
>   branch; and three bowls made like almonds in the other branch, with a
>   knop and a flower: so in the six branches that come out of the
>   candlestick.
>
> 34 And in the candlestick shall be four bowls made like unto almonds,
>   with their knops and their flowers.

The candlestick is a type of the redeemed church standing before his presence fashioned and glorified with Gold, (representing his Divinitity), almonds, knops and flowers, a token of the work of His grace.

Comment: Almond blossoms=grace, a fair representation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see what the almonds on the Menorah represent (symbol, meaning) in **Exodus 37:20** we really have to wander a little bit inside the Bible and some more.

First about the fruit: in Israel, the flowering of the almond marks the beginning of the agricultural season. It is the first fruit tree to flower, often even in January/February. Can tolerate aridity better than many other trees. Very drought resistant. However, it seems that it takes quite a while until the fruit is good to eat.

- See more in Lytton John Musselman, *A Dictionary of Bible Plants*,
  Cambridge University Press, 2011, p. 17

The word for *almond* (שָׁקֵד) is related to the the stem *sh-k-d*, which means “to be watchful, wakeful, vigilant”; thus, the almond flower is a symbol of life renewed and sustained.

- See N. M. Sarna, *Exodus. English and Hebrew; commentary in English in
  The JPS Torah commentary*, Jewish Publication Society, Philadelphia,
  1991, p. 165

Basically we could stop here. *Almond = life renewed and sustained by God's power at work*. Yet there is some more.

Now the full description of the Menorah is in **Exodus 37:17-22**. And there is another one, almost alike, in **Exodus 25:31-34**. Parallel:

> **Exodus 25:31-34** “You shall make a lampstand of pure gold. The lampstand shall be made of hammered work: its base, its stem, its
>   cups, its calyxes, and its flowers shall be of one piece with it. And
>   there shall be six branches going out of its sides, three branches of
>   the lampstand out of one side of it and three branches of the
>   lampstand out of the other side of it; three cups made like almond
>   blossoms  ... (**ESV**)
>
> **Exodus 37:19-20** .... three cups made like almond blossoms, each with calyx and flower, on one branch, and three cups made like almond
>   blossoms, each with calyx and flower, on the other branch - so for the
>   six branches going out of the lampstand. In the lampstand there were
>   four cups shaped like almond blossoms, its bulbs and its flowers
>   …(**ESV**)

We shall return to this. Let's have a ride first.

In **Genesis 30:37**, Jacob uses branches of almond in his attempt to influence the breeding of the flocks.

> **Genesis 30:37** Then Jacob took fresh sticks of poplar and almond [לוּז] and plane trees, and peeled white streaks in them, exposing the
>   white of the sticks. (**ESV**)

Yet the word used up here is different: לוּז. Not sure if this is of any help.

Further on, in **Genesis 43:11**, almond nuts are included in Jacob's gift for Egypt, during the famine.

> **Genesis 43:11** Then their father Israel said to them, “If it must be so, then do this: take some of the choice fruits of the land in
>   your bags, and carry a present down to the man, a little balm and a
>   little honey, gum, myrrh, pistachio nuts, and almonds.(**ESV**)

This could be significant, as almonds appear to be as something precious.

A very interesting **Numbers 17:8** is giving us a a testimony of the work of God, who has chosen the person who is going to be the high priest.

> **Numbers 17:8** When he went into the Tabernacle of the Covenant the next day, he found that Aaron's staff, representing the tribe of Levi,
>   had sprouted, budded, blossomed, and produced ripe almonds! (**ESV**)

So it is a sign of God's presence among Israel.

From **Jeremiah 1:11-12** we can find out more about this presence:

> **Jeremiah 1:11-12** And the word of the Lord came to me, saying, “Jeremiah, what do you see?” And I said, “I see an *almond* (שָׁקֵד)
>   branch.” Then the Lord said to me, “You have seen well, for I am
>   *watching* (שָׁקַד ) over my word to perform it.” (**ESV**)

Here is the mysterious yet relevant play on words of שָׁקֵד (*almond*) and שָׁקַד (*to watch, to be alert, to guard, to keep a close watch on something or someone*, especially of God’s watching over His word to fulfill it). In order to encourage Jeremiah in his very difficult prophetic work, God is giving him this vision of an almond, symbolizing God’s watchfulness and constant readiness to keep his promises. Basically God is telling Jeremiah he is not to be afraid in announcing Judah’s doom, because God would strengthen and defend him (see **Jeremiah 1:17–19**).

It is interesting [how the Talmud (TJ) is reading this](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15998#showrashi=true&v=12), connecting two different historical events: the breaching of the walls of Jerusalem by Nebuchadnezzar (in 586 b.c.e.) and by Titus (in 70 c.e.)

> **Ta'an. 4:8, 68c** "Just as 21 days elapse from the time of the almond sends forth his blossom until the fruit ripens, so 21 days
>   passed from the time the city was breached until the Temple was
>   destroyed."

- See also **Ecc. Rabbah 12:8**

More or less the same idea of God’s watching, in **Zechariah 4:2-6, 10**:

> **Zechariah 4:2-6, 10** And he said to me, “What do you see?” I said, “I see, and behold, a lampstand all of gold, with a bowl on the top of
>   it, and seven lamps on it, with seven lips on each of the lamps that
>   are on the top of it. [...] And I said to the angel who talked with
>   me, “What are these, my lord?” So the angel who was speaking with me
>   answered and said to me, "Do you not know what these are?" And I said,
>   "No, my lord." Then he said to me, “This is the word of the Lord to
>   Zerubbabel [...] **(10)**  “These seven are the eyes of the Lord, which
>   range through the whole earth.” (**ESV**) / (The seven lamps represent
>   the eyes of the Lord that search all around the world.) (**NLT**)

Exactly, the seven lamps are a symbol of the eyes of God, watching over His word to fulfill it. Is this that the lampstand, or Menorah, must symbolize God’s own presence? Well, this is why it is called Lamp of the Presence, isn't it?

No wonder the Rabbis interpreted the Menorah as a symbol of Israel and its mission to be “a light unto the nations”.

> **Shabbath 22 b**: [The light of the Menorah](https://halakhah.com/shabbath/shabbath_22.html#PARTb) it is a testimony to mankind that the Divine Presence rests in Israel.

- For a relevant comment on this, please see, M. A. Fishbane,
  *Haftarot. The JPS Bible commentary*, The Jewish Publication Society, Philadelphia, 2002, p. 224 *sq*. See also R. L. Eisenberg, *The JPS guide to Jewish traditions* (1st ed.), The Jewish Publication Society, Philadelphia, 2004, p. 579

> **Isaiah 42:6** I am the LORD; I have called you in righteousness; I will take you by the hand and keep you; I will give you as a covenant
>   for the people, a light for the nations ... (**ESV**)

All these actions of God as described in **Isaiah 42:6**: *calling, taking by the hand, keeping* - can be understood as part of  the work of God, *watching over* His word to fulfill it. And this work as symbolized by the almond.

Interesting enough, we meet this up in a NT prophetic fragment:

> **Revelation 1:12-13** Then I turned to see the voice that was speaking to me, and on turning I saw seven golden lampstands, and
>   among the lampstands was One like the Son of Man ... (**ESV**)

Very similar to **Jeremiah 1:11-12** and **Zechariah 4:2-6**, isn't it? If there is any connection among these, I would dare to go further and read them both in connection with **Deuteronomy 7:9**.

> **Deuteronomy 7:9** Know therefore that the LORD your God is God, the faithful God who keeps covenant and steadfast love with those who love
>   him and keep his commandments, to a thousand generations ... (**ESV**)

It is all about the same idea of God, watching over His word to fulfill it. As we got here, perhaps we can add that the almond may be understood as a symbol of the Covenant too.

**Now to conclude**: the almonds on the Menorah as described in Exodus 37:20 would represent:

1. the work of God continually watching over His word in order to keep
   and fulfill the Covenant;
2. the Covenant in itself;
3. Israel and its mission to be “a light unto the nations”;
4. the life of man renewed and sustained by God's power at work.

**Last but not least**, there is one more text, revealing a possible 5th meaning of the almond:

> **Ecclesiastes 12:5** Furthermore, men are afraid of a high place and of terrors on the road; the almond tree blossoms, the grasshopper
>   drags himself along, and the caperberry is ineffective. For man goes
>   to his eternal home while mourners go about in the street (**ESV**).

Here, the almond describes the short cycle of human life. Therefore the almonds on the Menorah can be a symbol of the human being too, who is called to preserve the light of God in order not be afraid "of a high place and of terrors on the road".

If you stay with me a little more on this, I'd quote a such a beautiful interpretation of Philo of Alexandria. It is rather related to Numbers 17, yet I think it is relevant for your question anyway:

**Philo, *On the Life of Moses*, II. XXXIV.180-186**

> XXXIV. (180) And the fruit were almonds, which is a fruit of a
>   different character from any other. For in most fruit, such as grapes,
>   olives, and apples, the seed and the eatable part differ from one
>   another, and being different are separated as to their position, for
>   the eatable part is outside, and the seed is shut up within; but in
>   the case of this fruit the seed and the eatable part are the same,
>   both of them being comprised in one species, and their position is one
>   and the same, being without strongly protected and fortified with a
>   twofold fence, consisting partly of a very thick bark, and partly of
>   what appears in no respect short of a wooden case,  (181) by which
>   perfect virtue is figuratively indicated. For as in the almond the
>   beginning and the end are the same, the beginning as far as it is
>   seed, and the end as far as it is fruit; so also is it the case with
>   the virtues; for each one of them is at the same time both beginning
>   and end, a beginning, because it proceeds not from any other power,
>   but from itself; and an end, because the life in accordance with
>   nature hastens towards it.  (182) This is one reason; and another is
>   also mentioned, more clear and emphatic than the former; for the part
>   of the almond which looks like bark is bitter, but that which lies
>   inside the bark, like a wooden case, is very hard and impenetrable, so
>   that the fruit, being enclosed in these two coverings, is not very
>   easily to be got at. (183) This is an emblem of the soul which is
>   inclined to the practice of meditation, from which he thinks it is
>   proper to turn it to virtue by showing it that it is necessary first
>   of all to encounter danger. But labour is a bitter, and distasteful,
>   and harsh thing, from which good is produced, for the sake of which
>   one must not yield to effeminate indolence;  (184) for he who seeks to
>   avoid labour is also avoiding good. And he, again, who encounters what
>   is disagreeable to be borne with fortitude and manly perseverance, is
>   taking the best road to happiness; for it is not the nature of virtue
>   to abide with those who are given up to delicacy and luxury, and who
>   have become effeminate in their souls, and whose bodies are enervated
>   by the incessant luxury which they practise every day; but it is
>   subdued by such conduct, and determined to change its abode, having
>   first of all arranged its departure so as to depart to, and abide
>   with, the ruler of right reason. (185) But, if I must tell the truth,
>   the most sacred company of prudence, and temperance, and courage, and
>   justice seeks the society of those who practise virtue, and of those
>   who admire a life of austerity and rigid duty, devoting themselves to
>   fortitude and self-denial, with wise economy and abstinence; by means
>   of which virtues the most powerful of all the principles within us,
>   namely, reason, improves and attains to a state of perfect health and
>   vigour, overthrowing the violent attacks of the body, which the
>   moderate use of wine, and epicurism, and licentiousness, and other
>   insatiable appetites excite against it, engendering a fulness of flesh
>   which is the direct enemy of shrewdness and wisdom. (186) Moreover, it
>   is said, that of all the trees that are accustomed to blossom in the
>   spring, the almond is the first to flourish, bringing as it were good
>   tidings of abundance of fruit; and that afterwards it is the last to
>   lose its leaves, extending the yearly old age of its verdure to the
>   longest period; in each of which particulars it is an emblem of the
>   tribe of the priesthood, as Moses intimates under the figure of this
>   tree that this tribe shall be the first of the whole human race to
>   flourish, and likewise the last; as long as it shall please God to
>   liken our life to the revolutions of the spring, destroying
>   covetousness that most treacherous of passions, and the fountain of
>   all unhappiness.

- Philo of Alexandria, *The works of Philo. Complete and unabridged*,
  C. D. Yonge (ed.), Hendrickson, Peabody, 1996, p. 507